# MOQ error setups not matched with Async / Await Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I am trying to figure out what I am missing here. My test runs fine but my MOQ `VerifyAll` is throwing an exception.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ActionPlanDataProvider_GetActionPlanReferenceList_ReturnsValid()
{
    try
    {
        //Arrange
        Mock<IActionPlanDataProvider> moqAPlan = new Mock<IActionPlanDataProvider>();
        //moqAPlan.Setup(x => x.GetActionPlanReferenceList()).ReturnsAsync(new ActionPlanReferenceList());
        moqAPlan
            .Setup(x => x.GetActionPlanReferenceList("1"))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(new ActionPlanReferenceList()));

        //Act
        var d = await moqAPlan.Object.GetActionPlanReferenceList("1234123");

        //Assert
        moqAPlan.VerifyAll();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string a = ex.Message;
        throw;
    }
}
```

> The following setups were not matched...

I'm wondering if this is because the way async runs that my MOQ doesn't see mocked object method call?

Comment: That happens when the Setup is not used. You set up the mock to use `GetActionPlanReferenceList("1")` but called `GetActionPlanReferenceList("1234123")`. So according to moq you didn't use the setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens when the Setup is not used. You set up the mock to use `GetActionPlanReferenceList("1")` but called `GetActionPlanReferenceList("1234123")`.

So according to moq what you executed didn't match what you setup.

You could either match the expected arguments or try

```
moqAPlan
    .Setup(x => x.GetActionPlanReferenceList(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(new ActionPlanReferenceList()));
```

which will let the method accept any string vai the `It.IsAny<string>()` expression argument

Comment: Appreciate the additional comment about It.IsAny +1